# I made Kolaczki dough with cream cheese butter and flour how long can i keep it in the refrigerator?

Tags: dough

I made kolaczki dough with butter cream cheese and flour how long can i keep it refrigerated

Comment: You can likely freeze it "indefinitely" (food safety) or for 2-3 months (quality, depending how well it's wrapped, sealed.) If the only ingredients are butter, cream cheese and flour, those all store quite well refrigerated separately, so it's reasonable to think that they will store fairly well mixed and refrigerated. Other ingredients might affect that thought.

Answer (score 1):

Butter and cream cheese contains some amount of water. And water from cheese and butter + sugars from flour makes it more friendly to mold and bacteria than any of ingredients separately. Also, your kitchen is not sterile. I wouldn't dare to store dough refrigerated for more than a week or two, wrapped well. Of course, your mileage may vary.

If you expect to store it longer than a week, cut it to smaller portion and freeze, in a way that you will allow you to unfreeze only the amount you want. Or, better yet, bake it all and give it to your friends. And when you need more, make more.

Answer (score 0):

When I make I always send some to my best friend who lives on the west coast (I live south east). I send them the day after baking, priority mail and if she keeps in fridge they mold within a couple days so she throws then in freezer, when she wants one, she takes it out and puts it in the counter to get to room temp. Yes, they mold in fridge. I've even had my dough mold when I didn't finish a batch quick enough.